# How to find a particular type of word and count it

Tags: python

I am trying to identify a particular word and then count it. I need to save the count for each identifier.

For example, a document may contain as below:

```
risk risk risk free interest rate 

asterisk risk risk 

market risk risk [risk
```

*I need to count 'risk' not asterisk. There could be other risk related words, so don't stick to the above example. What I need to find is 'risk'. If risk ends with or starts with anything like < [ ( or . ! * > ] ), etc.. I need to count it as well. But if risk word is a component of a word like asterisk, then I should not count it.

Here is what I have so far. However, it returns a count for asterisk and [risk as well as risk. I tried to use regular expression but keep getting errors. Plus, I am a beginner of Python. If anyone has any idea, please help me!!^^ Thanks.

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_dict=defaultdict(int)

for line in mylist:
    words=line.lower().split()  # converted all words to lower case
    for word in words:
        word_dict[word]+=1

for word in word_dict:
    if 'risk' in word:
       word, word_dict[word]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace words, count a word, and save the count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223937/how-to-replace-words-count-a-word-and-save-the-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 'risk' == word:
    print word, word_dict[word]
```

Comment: "if risk ends with or starts with anything like < [ ( or . ! * > ] ), etc.. I need to count it as well." .. does this do that?

Comment: @Levon: Of cause not, if you want that way, you'd better to use regular express.

Comment: So your solution does *not* work. It's not what I want, it's what OP is asking help for.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy to do this with regular expressions:

```
import re
haystack = "risk asterisk risk brisk risk"
prog = re.compile(r'\brisk\b')
result = re.findall(prog, haystack)
print len(result)
```

This outputs "3".

The \b regexp means any word delimiter including end/beginning of line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, there could be so many different words that contain risk. Thus, I guess I cannot just compile. I will post a question with a more clear explanation. Sorry.

Comment: So you're trying to count the number of occurrences of *any* word? You could do r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b' and then the sort the result array, and parse it to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Jimmy you could modify the regex: `r'\w+'`. If it is not enough you could look at various nltk tokenizers. Also you can [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12223803/edit)  instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry. I am a beginner, so I though i had to post a new one whenever I have one. I will do so next time.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression `(?<![a-zA-Z])risk(?![a-zA-Z])` should match "risk" if it's not preceded or followed by another letter. For example:

```
>>> len(re.findall('(?<![a-zA-Z])risk(?![a-zA-Z])','risk? 1risk asterisk risky'))
2
```

Here's the breakdown of this re:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` This negative lookbehind assertion says that the match will only happen if it is not preceded by a match for `[a-zA-Z]`, which in turn just matches a letter.
- `risk` This is the central re that matches "risk"; nothing fancy here...
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` This is similar to the first part. It is a negative lookahead assertion that makes the match happen only if it is not followed by a letter.

So, say you also don't want to match things like "1risk" that have numbers before them. You can just change the `[a-zA-Z]` portion of the re to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Eg.:

```
>>> len(re.findall('(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])risk(?![a-zA-Z0-9])','risk? 1risk asterisk risky'))
1
```

**Update:**
In response to your question [How to replace words, count a word, and save the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223937/how-to-replace-words-count-a-word-and-save-the-count), I now get what you are asking for. You can use the same type of structure I have shown you, but modified to include all of these words:

- risk
- risked
- riskier
- riskiest
- riskily
- riskiness
- risking
- risks
- risky

There are a couple ways to modify the original re; the most intuitive is probably to just use the re OR `|` and add in `\-` to the negative lookahead to prevent matching on "risk-free" and such. For example:

```
>>> words = '|'.join(["risk","risked","riskier","riskiest","riskily","riskiness","risking","risks","risky"])
>>> len(re.findall('(?<![a-zA-Z])(%s)(?![a-zA-Z\-])' % words, 'risk? 1risk risky risk-free'))
3
```

Comment: I need to use that expression for a file and search for all the risk. Then, how can I do that using findall function? I cannot put a file name instead of the text. I also need to find all risk words, so don't I need to use for ... in.. ?

Comment: Well, you could do a variety of things. If you know the file's small, you could read in the whole file to a string and use the re on that. (Not recommended b/c if the file is too big... bad things.) The safer thing to do is to open the file, loop over the lines, and use the findall on each line. Then you can add up the number found for each line to get the number of "risk"s in the whole file.