# How to replace words, count a word, and save the count

Tags: python

I need to first replace risk related words such as risky riskier riskless [risk] (risk) risk. risk! risk* into risk and count only risk and return it.

When doint so, there are some conditions. I should not count 'risk-' and any words that have risk as a component like asterisk.

For example, in a long document, there could be so many risk related words. To simplify the explanation,

#

I like to take risk. I don't like to take a riskier route.

How much is the risk-free interest rate?

What is asterisk? [risk] is risk.

#

from the above document,
1) Need to replace risk and riskier into risk. (there could be other words too so don't stick to riskier).
2) count only risk including [risk] risk. but not risk- and asterisk.

The example is very much simplified. Again, 'risk', any words like risky riskless riskness riskier, any 'risk' inside ([{, any 'risk' that is preceded or ended with .*!? etc..   should be counted after replacing it into risk. Anywords that contain risk as a component should not be counted. Also, risk- should not be counted.

Thanks.

market risk risk [risk

Comment: After replacing risk+some string (risky riskier) into risk, removing risk-, then I did this. Doing so many steps separately take too much time.                                                                  from collections import defaultdict
>>> word_dict = defaultdict(int)
>>> for line in mylist:
 words = line.lower().split()
 for word in words:
  word_dict[word]+=1

  
>>> for word in word_dict:
 if 'risk' in word:
  word, word_dict[word]

  
('risk', 7)
('asterisk', 1)
('[risk', 1)

Comment: note: in general you might need something like [nltk.stem](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a matter of how to compose the the Regular Expression. I'm not very good at RE. But the following works in terms of your example:

```py
>>> import re
>>> a= '''I like to take risk. I don't like to take a riskier route.
How much is the risk-free interest rate?
What is asterisk? [risk] is risk. '''
>>> pattern=r'\brisk[^\-]?\w*\b'
>>> re.subn(pattern,'risk',astr)
("\nI like to take risk. I don't like to take a risk route.\nHow much is the risk-free interest rate?\nWhat is asterisk? [risk] is risk.\n" , 5)
```

---

Based on the above, you may can realize you logic as:

```py
counts=0
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    with open(my_new_file, 'a') as fo:
        for line in f:
            newline, lcount= re.subn(pattern,'risk',line)
            counts+=lcount
            fo.write(newline)
```

Comment: I got an error. It says counts are not defined. What does 'a' option mean?

Comment: 'a' option is for appending. (see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open))

Comment: 'a' means "append", one of the three mode(i.e, read-r, write-w, append-a) when you open a file.

Comment: @Jimmy, `counts=0` defines the `counts` variable at the start of John's second code snippet.  Did you miss that line?  Otherwise, please post the exact error message.